# get specific keys from database

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm trying to get some specific keys and values from the database. My database entries look like so:

```
id | name | description      | value
------------------------------------------
1  | lang | default language | en
2  | date | date format      | YYYY-MM-DD
```

I want to echo only my `name` and `value` fields. I've tried using a nested foreach loop, like so:

```
foreach($details as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $index => $row)
    {
        echo $index . " / " . $row . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

But that only echos:

```
id / 1
name / lang
description / default language
value / en

id / 2
name / date
description / date format
value / YYYY-MM-DD
```

However, when I add an offset, like so: `$index[1]`, I get this like `a` instead of name, or `e` instead of `description`.

I've previously worked from `while` loops using `mysql_fetch_array`, but this would give me a repeated element (say a `<tr>`) whereas I simply need to extract the value of the field because this will be used to build a form for the user to manage.

Would anyone have a suggestion or different approach for me to do something of the sort ?

**EDIT**

The query comes from a class file:

```
// extracted from my queries.class.php
public function my_prefs()
{
   global $db;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE value!=NULL";
   return $db->select($query);
}
// extracted from the source file 
$module_details = $query->my_prefs();
```

**EDIT #2**

Perhaps this will help you understand my needs:

```
foreach($module_details as $key => $value)
{
    print_r($module_details);
}
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => lang
        [description] => default language
        [value] => en
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => date
        [description] => date format
        [value] => YYYY-MM-DD
    )
}
```

I need to access only `lang` / `en` and `date` / `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: what is the database query that you are using and what do you want the end result to look like ?

Comment: Can you post more code including how you're grabbing the info from the db? This should be straight forward if we can see what you're doing.

Comment: what does $details look like ? where is it coming from ?

Comment: sounds like you need to learn basic PHP before endeavoring in databases and complex systems. [see the docs about arrays](http://www.php.net/arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around to getting something to work. Here's what I did:

```
foreach($details as $row)
{
    $name = $row->name;
    $value = $row->value;

    // In order to specify for checkboxes, select, radio, etc.
    if($name == "lang")
    {
        // different info depending on the value
    }
    else
    {
        // do something generic here
    }
}
```

Might not be an optimal option, but this works like I need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question..

But I believe you are trying to access the specific column entry from the array. You can do this by using the keys you are outputting instead of using a numeric index.

```
foreach($details as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['name'];
   echo $value['value'];
   echo "<br />";
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to limit the results from your query so you only have the fields you requested replace:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE value!=NULL";
```

with

```
 $query = "SELECT name, value FROM preferences WHERE value!=NULL";
```

Comment: my answer is similar to yours and was down-voted as well. Someone hates us.

Comment: added a 2nd edit with example output and what I need from this

Comment: I believe thats exactly what my answer does... Are you trying to limit your query instead?

Comment: No, in fact, I need to be able to call upon my column "value" to add to my HTML input tag, like so: <input type="text" id="width" name="width" value="<?php echo $details['value']; ?>" /> type of thing, and some values will be dropdown menus, checkboxes, radio buttons... I just need to verify and echo my values.

Comment: I believe thats what my first answer does. If you need more info on accessing the arrary try a var_dump( $arrayName ); it will print out the array contents as well as their keys/value

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($details as $key => $value)
{
    // "name" => "value" dictionary later access
    $tmp[$value["name"]] = $value["value"]; 
    echo $value["name"] . " = " . $value["name"]; // echos e.q. "date = YYYY-MM-DD"
    echo "<br/>";
}

echo $tmp["date"]; // echos e.q. "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here... why the `$tmp` array?

Comment: @NDM take a look at my comment `"... for later access"`. Could be helpful.

Comment: ah, yes a dictionary with the requested values may be handy; had to edit to unlock my vote :)